# Foreign key constraint with a "where"

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to have a foreign key constraint with a where?

```
CREATE TABLE child_version_2_parent_data (
  child_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ...some other meta data...
)

CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES parent WHERE version = 2,
  version int
)
```

I have a table where there are about 100 million rows (version 1 - basically legacy rows) that don't have a parent. And in the next version, all the new rows will have a parent row

Comment: If you want to ensure all rows with `version = 2` has `NOT NULL` `child_id` you may just use `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: Sorry to clarify. child_id on the child table is the primary key. All rows have child id on this table

Comment: I want to enforce a foreign key constraint on version 2 child rows to refer to another table

Answer (score 1):

the way I would express this is to allow the `child_id` column to be null, but with a `references parent`, and to enforce the "correctness", add an additional `check constraint (version < 2 OR child_id is not NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

The technically correct way to represent your data is to have different tables for different versions.